# Prepare images for a neural network model

Tags: python, neural-network, computer-vision

I have written the following to load and prepare images for neural network model, not
for the deep convolutional neural network.
Steps: Scan -> resize -> flatten -> normalize.
I don't use OpenCV or filtering pooling methods. It is a simple function that read, resize then flatten the images.
Images extension are .jpg

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from skimage.transform import resize
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def load_pre_images(fname_csv, path, num_px):

    """


        Parameters
        ----------
        path : str
            Path to images folder
        fname_csv : str
            Name of the CSV file that contains [Images_names, description, 
            target]
         num_px : int
            Images new size (num_px x num_px)
        Returns
        -------
        np.array(img_dataset) : numpy array
            Complete data (m x nx)
            m is the number of pictures
            nx is the dimensionality (num_px x num_px x 3) for rbg images
        count : int
            Count of the undetected images

    """

    img_dataset = []
    mydata = pd.read_csv(path + fname_csv).values
    count = 0
    for i in mydata:
        try:
            img_path = path_images + i[0] + '.jpg'  # Images names lies in the first column
            image = plt.imread(img_path)
            my_image = resize(image, (num_px, num_px)).reshape((num_px*num_px*3,1)) # Flatten
            my_image = my_image / 255  # Normalize images
            img_dataset.append(np.append(my_image, i[2]))  # Target lies in the third column
        except FileNotFoundError:
            count += 1
            continue
    return np.array(img_dataset), count

path_images = 'your path to the images folder/'
imgs, c = load_pre_images('name_of_your_csv_file.csv', path_images, 100)
```

Is it good to use numpy append 'img_dataset.append(np.append(my_image, i[2]))' or there is a better way to do that?

Comment: I don't understand. What kind of help are you looking for ?

Comment: Sorry about that. I would like to know your opinion about my code. (How can I improve it?)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, why would you use `imread` from matplotlib when you're already importing skimage? Use `skimage.io.imread`

Second, I don't quite get what you're trying to do with the whole `numpy.append` thing. That's both flattening your image and appending the target value to the end of it, but there are better ways of doing it. Here's a simple code to do exactly what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.io import imread
import os


def load_pre_images(fname_csv, path, num_px):
    """
        Parameters
        ----------
        path : str
            Path to images folder
        fname_csv : str
            Name of the CSV file that contains [Images_names, description, 
            target]
         num_px : int
            Images new size (num_px x num_px)
        Returns
        -------
        np.array(img_dataset) : numpy array
            Complete data (m x nx)
            m is the number of pictures
            nx is the dimensionality (num_px x num_px x 3) for rbg images
        count : int
            Count of the undetected images

    """

    mydata = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, fname_csv)).values
    count = 0
    x = []
    y = []
    for row in mydata:
        try:
            img_path = os.path.join(path, row[0] + '.jpg')  # Images names lies in the first column
            image = imread(img_path)
            my_image = resize(image, (num_px, num_px))
            my_image = my_image / 255  # Normalize images
            my_image = my_image.reshape((-1, 1))  # Flatten image
            x.append(my_image)
            y.append(row[2])
        except FileNotFoundError:
            count += 1
            continue
    return np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y), count


path_images = 'your path to the images folder/'
imgs, labels, c = load_pre_images('name_of_your_csv_file.csv', path_images, 100)
```

See that I have:

1. Removed the unnecessary matplotlib dependency
2. Separated images and labels into different arrays
3. Changed the `except Exception` to `except FileNotFoundError`, cause that's probably what you want. Don't go catching all exceptions in a single clause. That's bad
4. Used `numpy.reshape` to flatten your image, instead of the `numpy.append` which is not made for that

Comment: I have corrected a missing part in my code as the output should be a matrix not a stack of lists. I added  .reshape((num_px*num_px*3,1))